# delay_sec is not accurate for deferred transaction

Tags: smart-contract, deferred-transactions

I have set some seconds but sometimes it is delayed more than 10 minutes. I know that `delay_sec` is not the accurate time because of the block production mechanism. The real time is much later than it *should* happen.

Comment: Hi @crax could you post the code you are using to set `delay_sec`?

Comment: just `delay_sec = 5`

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the telegram by admin Todd Fleming:

> There is no guarantee that delayed transactions will execute on time, or at all. Trying to make guarantees like that would compromise the integrity of the chain.